# Is any fusion or fission happening at the center of Earth?

Tags: earth, fusion

High pressure, temperature same as the surface of the Sun, solid iron inner core, liquid outer heavy elements core - got it. But are nuclear reactions happening there?

Comment: Fission occurred very near the surface in Oklo ( Gabon ) Africa.

Comment: Uranium-$238$ fission in the Earth's centre is why most of it is still molten. It drives the convection currents responsible for tectonic drift.